# Spectrum of cycle graph

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

I am asked to find the spectrum of the cycle graphs $C_n$.

In a previous exercise, I found the eigenvalues of $A_n$, where

$$(A_n)_{ij}=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }j=i+1\mod n \\ 0 &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Those were $\lambda=\exp \left(\frac{2\pi ik}{n}\right)$ for $k \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$.

It seems that the adjacency matrix of $C_n$ is equal to $A_n+A_n^\top$, but I have no idea how to proceed.

I also have trouble finding the spectrum of $K_n$. This seems to be the same trick, by noticing that the adjacency matrix of $K_n$ is $J-I$ where $J$ is the matrix with all ones.

Comment: $J$ is a rank-1 matrix with eigenvalues $n,0,0,\ldots$, hence the spectrum of $J-I$ is $n-1,-1,-1,\ldots$.

Comment: @Jack thanks! That is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $K_n$ the computation is simple:

$A+I$ has rank 1, hence $-1$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity at least $n-1$. To find the last eigenvalue use the fact that 
$$-1+(-1)+...+(-1)+\lambda_n=tr(A)=0$$

For the cycle graph, let $v=(1, \omega, \omega ^2,.., \omega^{n-1})$, where $\omega$ is a nth root of unity. What is $Av$?

Answer (score 0):

The adjacency matrix $B=A_n+A_n^t$ is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).
The eigenvectors of a circulant matrix are always $v_k=(1,\zeta^k,
\zeta^{2k},\ldots,\zeta^{(n-1)k})$, for integers $k$,  where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/n)$.
So the eigenvalues of $B$ are $\zeta^k+\zeta^{-k}=2\cos(2\pi k/n)$
for $0\le k<n$.