# Spectrum of the n-cycle graph $C_n$, $n\ge3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I am looking for the spectrum of a cycle graph i.e, eigenvalues of adjacency matrix of $C_n$ and their multiplicities.

I know that the adjacency matrix of $C_n$ is always a circulant matrix. Hence, using the fact that the eigenvalues of any circulant matrix with its first row as $(c_o,c_{n-1},c_{n-2},....,c_1)$ is given by $\lambda_j = c_o+c_{n-1}w_j+c_{n-2}w_j^2+....+c_1w_j^{n-1}$,    $j=0,1,....,n-1$, where $w_j=exp\big(i\frac{2\pi j}{n}\big)$, we can compute all the eigenvalues.

But I am looking for a way where we could find the spectrum of $C_n$, independent of the concept of circulant matrices.

Is there any other way to find the spectrum of $C_n$?

I am looking for another way other than the one I mentioned above, please.
This is't a duplicate question.

It is easy to say that 2 is always an eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of any $C_n, n\ge3$, with multiplicity 1, but what about other eigenvalues?

Comment: you could see the analysis for permutation matrices. In the last part you mean $1$ is eigenvalue not $2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spectrum of cycle graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726624/spectrum-of-cycle-graph)

Comment: @ToniMhax I think it is 2, because the sum of the entries of a column of the matrix would be an eigenvalue, since that sum is same for any column of the matrix as every vertex is adjacent to exactly 2 vertices. 
But if you think 1 is also an eigenvalue, how?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil No, because one of the answer was considering the adjacency matrix as a circulant matrix. But as I asked, I'm looking for another way. 

And in another answer, do you know how can we find the eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix of the cycle graph using that matrix A? Thank you for sharing it tho.

Comment: yes i missed a thing. Tx, if there is a direct proof it won't be easy. To check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of a cycle permutation on $n$ vertices, or a cyclic *directed* graph with edges pointing only one way. For example, such a cycle matrix $M_4$ on four vertices would look like
$$ M_4 = \begin{pmatrix} & & & 1 \\ 1 & & & \\ & 1 & & \\ & & 1 & \end{pmatrix} $$
You can see that for this matrix $M_n$ that we have $M_n^n = I$, and furthermore $M_n^k \neq I$ for any $1 \leq k < n$. So the characteristic polynomial of this matrix is the same as the minimal polynomial, and is $(x^n - 1)$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $M_n$ are the $n$th roots of unity, $1, \omega, \omega^2, \ldots, \omega^{n-1}$ where $\omega = \exp(2 \pi i / n)$.

Now you need to somehow see that the eigenvectors of this matrix $M_n$ are of the form $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$, $(1, \omega, \omega^2, \ldots, \omega^{n-1})$, $(1, \omega^2, \omega^4, \ldots, \omega^{2n - 2})$ with eigenvalues $1, \omega, \omega^2$ and so on. (This is not hard to do if you explicitly write out a vector, declare it to be an eigenvector with a certain eigenvalue and just apply the matrix to it and check the conditions).

Now comes the last part. The matrix $M_n^{-1}$ has the *same* eigenvectors, with inverse eigenvalues. So the vector $(1, \omega^2, \omega^4, \ldots, \omega^{2n - 2})$ is an $M_n$-eigenvector with eigenvalue $\omega^2$, and an $M_n^{-1}$-eigenvector with eigenvalue $\omega^{-2}$. Therefore their sum $M_n + M_n^{-1}$ has eigenvalues $1 + 1 = 2$, $\omega + \omega^{-1} = 2 \cos (2 \pi / n)$, $\omega^2 + \omega^{-2} = 2 \cos(4 \pi / n)$, and so on. Furthermore, $M_n + M_n^{-1}$ is the adjacency matrix of the cycle graph.

Comment: Why is the characteristic polynomial equal to the minimal polynomial of $M_n$?